# Product management system

Tags: database, content-management-system

We are looking for a system that is able to do the following:
Browse trough records containing plain text data (name/ID's/suppliers/show links etc) but is also able to store pdf's that go along with this information.
The system should preferably be server/web based to be accesible over intranet.

Any idea's?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two opposite ways to solve IT tasks. Take something that fits your requirements or build it yourself. Your task sounds not so complicated and so I think one solution could be to set it up yourself. (Or ask somebody to do so.)

I would prefer [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) as the programming language, the [dancer](/questions/tagged/dancer) web framework and may be a [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) to store your data. You can easily run the app with [starmen](/questions/tagged/starmen) and use [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) in front of it as proxy.

This environment is easy to expand to your needs and would fit exactly to your reqiurements, nothing more nothing less.